# Códigos iguais, saídas diferentes

Tags: python, while

Por que no código

```
x = 1
while (x < 4):
    x = x + 1
print ("x vale", x)
```

possui apenas uma saída 4, e em

```
i = 6
while (i > 0):
    i = i - 3
    print (i)
```

A saída é diferente.

Comment: Acho que faltou continuar o pensamento: "...possui apenas uma saída `4`, enquanto o código a seguir tem duas sáidas `0` e `3`..."

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta tem uma premissa claramente errada, não são códigos iguais, eles são bem diferentes. Qualquer mudança no código, mínima que seja, poderá produzir resultados diferentes.

O primeiro valor começa valendo 1 e terá 3 interações porque em cada uma o valor da variável incrementa em 1 e a condição estabelece que no momento que chega em 4 deve encerar o laço.

Na verdade o código assim não faz o menor sentido porque é certeza que o código sempre imprimirá 4, então é melhor mandar imprimir 4 sem fazer mais nada. Faça o código ser o mais simples possível.

Pode ser que queria que o primeiro código imprimisse 2, 3, 4 em cada linha. Isso só aconteceria se o `print()` estivesse no mesmo bloco do `while`, assim:

```
x = 1
while (x < 4):
    x = x + 1
    print ("x vale", x)
```

Note que pela ordem das coisas não imprime o número 1, o incremento teria que vir depois da impressão para imprimir o 1, aí não imprimiria o 4.

O segundo código já começa diferente porque o valor inicial da variável é 6 e a condição para encerrar o laço é que o valor tem que ser maior que 0. Internamente em cada passo a variável terá seu valor reduzido em 3. Então no primeiro passo a variável passará valer 3, e no segundo passo valerá 0, por isso não haverá um terceiro passo já que a condição passa ser falsa.

Outra grande diferença é que a impressão do valor está dentro do laço (ele está indentado, tem um espaçamento indicando que ele faz parte daquele bloco e não de outro mais externo). Então em cada passo é impresso o valor. No final do laço nada é impresso, não tem um comando fora dele como tem no primeiro código.

Se queria que só aparecesse o valor final então o `print()` deveria estar fora do laço. Ele será sempre 0, mas em algum caso que o valor inicial fosse diferente o final poderia não ser 0. Assim:

```
i = 6
while (i > 0):
    i = i - 3
print (i)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/DecrementLoop.py).

É uma forma de fazer, mas é muito mais simples fazer sem o laço. Eu entendo que está querendo demonstrar algo no algoritmo, mas ele não é necessário, é bom ter claro isso.

Obviamente tem diferenças menores, como o nome da variável que não muda nada, e na primeira impressão tem um texto além do valor.

Comment: muito obrigada!

Comment: @VivianJunqueira veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Comment: na verdade, eu queria entender porque um dava direto o resultado final e no outro dava os resultados conforme a repetição... mas já entendi que o print comanda isso! 
não estava enxergando isto.
quando quis dizer que eram iguais era porque a estrutura pra mim estava parecida, novamente já percebi que não estão!
muitissimo obrigada :)!

Answer (score 1):

O python só entende que o `print (i)` faz parte do while se o mesmo estiver dentro do escopo do loop. Tente identar o print para que o mesmo fique dentro do escopo do while dessa forma:

```
x = 1
while (x < 4):
    x = x + 1
    print ("x vale", x)

    # Output
    # x vale 2
    # x vale 3
    # x vale 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?
Dentro do Python, cada espaço serve para indentação, que é usado para definir estruturas. Por exemplo, se eu quiser mostrar uma contagem de 0 a 10 no Python, eu faço isso:

```
i = 0
while i<10:
   i += 1 #mesma coisa que i = i + 1
   print(i)
```

se eu fizesse sem o espaço no "print(i), ele entenderia que essa linha só será executada quando a estrutura terminasse, aí só mostraria o valor 10.
Detalhe: é bom tomar cuidado com indentação, pois ela deve ser igual para todos os comandos de uma mesma estrutura. Por exemplo, se vc faz uma repetição dessa, mas dá uns 2 espaços sem querer em um dos comandos, ele vai entender que um deles está fora da indentação, e dará uma mensagem de erro.
Não sei esclareci suas dúvidas, mas espero ter ajudado :-)